# Space between lines in shellscript being taken as a command

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I am writing a `bash script` which is a follows

```
#!/bin/bash

#getting the environment variable from commandline
environment=$1

echo $environment
```

Now when I run the script with `bash ./bashScript.sh Hello` , I get the following errors on line

> : command not found line 2
>
> : command not found line 5

I see that both of these lines are space and bash script is thus giving me an error

To solve it I write my script as

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#getting the environment variable from commandline
environment=$1
#
echo $environment
```

But it looks kind of messy

Is there any other way to achieve this. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Did you copy it from somewhere? Sounds like you might have some stray line endings or something along those lines

Comment: @arco444 No I have written it myself. The space between lines is due to `enter` being pressed on keyboard

Comment: I agree with @arco444 , I try your first code fragment and it works fine for me.

Comment: When you suspect non printable characters in a file, `hexdump` or `od` allow to make sure of the file content at the byte level: `od -xc file` gives an hexadecimal dump of the file, the output of which should make the problem evident.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I can see   `\r  \n  \r  \n` after bash when I try the above command

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri: Just do `dos2unix <file>` and try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment add the precision that your lines use DOS end of lines (`\r\n`) when you dump it with `od -xc file`. To avoid it, you should make sure that your editor uses Unix end of lines (`\n`).

To fix it on an existing text file, you can use `tr`:

```
tr -d '\r' < dos_file > unix_file
```

Comment: Thanks for help :) Really appreciate it